# Segments on the plot

Tags: r

I want to draw several (lets say - 5 for now) segments on my plot. I've tried segments() function but it draws only two segments out of 5 given coordinates. Here is the code :

```
    begs  <- c(34573131,35072050,35471145, 35746065,36504818)
    ends  <- c(34887083,35139735,35557793,35789178,36950091)
    step <- 820000

    plot(1, xlim = c(33900000,38000000), axes = F, xlab="Position")
    axis(1, at = seq(33900000,38000000, by=step), labels=format(seq(33900000,38000000, by=step)/1e6, scientific=F, digits=3))
    axis(4, at = seq(0,2,length.out = 5), labels = seq(0,2,length.out = 5) )
    segments(x0 = begs, x1 = ends, y0 = c(0.1, 0.5 , 0.9 ,1.4, 1.9))
```

and the plot looks like that :
[image: segments]

Comment: Your y axis is not long enough. Add `ylim=c(0,2)` to your `plot()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call to `plot()` causes R to calculate the x and y range.  Thus if your data in this first call is not representative of the range, you need to specify the range manually.

Concretely, add `ylim=c(...)` to your `plot()` call:

Try this:

```
min <- 33900000
max <- 38000000

plot(1, xlim = c(min, max), ylim=c(0, 2), 
     axes = FALSE, xlab="Position", ylab="", type="n")

axis(1, at = seq(min, max, by=step), labels=format(seq(min, max, by=step)/1e6,
     scientific=F, digits=3))
axis(4, at = seq(0,2,length.out = 5), labels = seq(0,2,length.out = 5) )
segments(x0 = begs, x1 = ends, y0 = c(0.1, 0.5 , 0.9 ,1.4, 1.9))
```

[image]